# SumIfs in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a requirement to sum all the cells in a column from a sheet called Raw Data.  But only if a few conditions exist.

1. The value in Raw Data column B matches the value of a offset from the current cell
2. The Month of the date in Raw Data Column C is less than or equal to H2
3. The Year of the date in Raw Data Column C is less than or equal to H2

Here is the formula I have assembled thus far:

```
=SUMIFS('Raw Data'!$D:$D,'Raw Data'!$B:$B,OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN())),0,-4),MONTH('Raw Data'!$C:$C),<=MONTH($H$2),YEAR('Raw Data'!$C:$C),<=YEAR($H$2))
```

It could be a simple syntax error, but I don;t think it is.  I keep getting a generic "There is a problem with the formula" error.

Can I get some help?

Comment: This cannot be a range `YEAR('Raw Data'!$C:$C),`

Comment: You are basically saying that if the date in column C:C is less then or equal to this month do the sum, correct?

Comment: Correct.  I was wondering if Month() and Year() would throw an issue with a Range.  What would a good replacement be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With SUMIFS the range expects a range not an array so `MONTH('Raw Data'!$C:$C)` and `YEAR('Raw Data'!$C:$C)` will not work.

Also when the others are expecting a string so you must use quotes and concatenate the criteria: `"<=" & value`

In this case we want everything less than the 1st of the next month:

```
"<" & EOMONTH($H$2,0)+1
```

Use this:

```
=SUMIFS('Raw Data'!$D:$D,'Raw Data'!$B:$B,OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN())),0,-4),'Raw Data'!$C:$C,"<" & EOMONTH($H$2,0)+1)
```

Comment: Will this also meet the criteria of the current year or less using EOMONTH?

Comment: Yes for example `EOMONTH(TODAY(),0)+1` will return `1/1/2018` so anything with a date less than that would be returned.

Comment: Awesome!  Also, thank you for the explanation to go with the answer.  This was VERY helpful.